# Vue 3 slot styles from child component

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-slot

**Summary**: I need to style the contents of a `<slot>`, from the child component. I'm using scoped css and the styles don't apply:

I have the following two components:

```html
<!-- Parent.vue -->
<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }} from Parent</h1>
  <Child>
    <h1>{{ msg }} from Child</h1>
  </Child>
</template>
...
<style scoped>
h1 {
  color: green;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!-- Child.vue -->
<template>
  <slot></slot>
</template>
...
<style scoped>
h1 {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

I want the 2nd `<h1>` to be red, but it's green, since the component is rendered with something like:

```html
<h1 data-v-452d6c4c data-v-2dcc19c8-s>Hello from Child</h1>

<style>
h1[data-v-452d6c4c] {
  color: green;
}
h1[data-v-2dcc19c8] {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

`data-v-452d6c4c` comes from Parent, and `data-v-2dcc19c8-s` from Child

If the second attribute, in the `<h1>` tag, was just `data-v-2dcc19c8` the style I wanted would be applied, but since it has that `-s` suffix (slot?), it doesn't.

I could probably find some other solution with a class or something, but I rarely use `<slot>` and I want to understand the inner workings. That `-s` tells me that what I'm trying to do can be dealt with the help of the framework, what am I missing?

A working sample:

https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-brown-ilfwn

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the new [`:slotted` selector](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-style.html#slotted-selectors) in Vue 3:

*Child.vue*

```html
<template>
  <slot></slot>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Child",
};
</script>

<style scoped>
:slotted(h1) {
  color: red !important;
}
</style>
```

In Vue 3, child `scoped` styles don't affect slotted content by default.

In your particular example, the `!important` modifier is also necessary because the parent also defined an `h1` style which would take precedence otherwise

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I have been looking for a way to do slotted styling in Vue for quite a while

Comment: Is there a page in the docs about this? Searching the docs for `v-slotted` doesn't show any results

Comment: @MikeHarrison - It's [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-style.html#slotted-selectors) and actually the syntax has changed again. Now you use `:slotted(h1)` instead of `::v-slotted(h1)`. The answer has been changed to reflect this.  (Reposted comment to fix link.)